# check jQuery object content returned by $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery

When we write a jQuery function like  $(document).ready() which return an jQuery Object,  how to check whether the Object  returned  is  empty  or any content inside it  (like is there any jQuery function for that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just look at the `.length` property of the returned object.

For example:

```
$('div').length;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the element available or not through .length property.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 if($('#spnText').length>0) {  
 } 
});
```

HTML:

```
<span id="spnText"/>
```